# How to visualize the laser scan data as a local/global map?

Tags: navigation, mapping, laser, ros-melodic, scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, my robot in ros melodic has a *lidar* and I want to visualize the *laser scan data*.

Previously I used the local_costmap, but since it became more complicated and now it consists not only of the laser scan data, I am searching for an alternative how to come to a *global map* or at least as a previous step, to a *local map* of a fixed size, similar to what *local_costmap* would give with only *one layer of laser scan data*.

I guess this is something common, so there should be already a way of doing this, but my search hasn't led me far. I basically need a map (*.png image / OccupancyGrid*) of what *rviz* already could visualize (only laser scan). I would appreciate any help, thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395093/how-to-visualize-the-laser-scan-data-as-a-local/global-map?/) by [ymag](https://answers.ros.org/users/94237/ymag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the package `gmappng` can be applied.

http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2022-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ymag](https://answers.ros.org/users/94237/ymag/) on 2022-01-28**:
Thank you, yes, gmapping is actually what I was looking for, but how can I do it from a script? I need an image of the global map with laser scan data so to say every two seconds, and I do not overwrite it, I collect them, so do you know how can I write this with python in a script and not from the terminal?

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2022-01-29**:
I think you can create a  node that keeps subscribing to the `map` topic and `scan` topic, and saves it every 2 seconds.
I think the content has changed from the original question, so if you want to continue, would you create another question?